# OOP: Create an Object to Draw Image

Tags: oop, draw, paint

I am going to build a drawing program (something like MS Paint) using Java. I have been able to draw basic shapes on a JFrame using Swing lib, but they are static, I cannot do anything with them. Therefore, I would like to make each shape an object that will store all information we need to manipulate such as sizing, rotating, changing color, exporting to jpeg image etc.

So I am thinking of creating an Image class with subclasses Rectangle, Oval etc. Each subclass will have an array of Points(x,y) so that we can manipulate each point. So if I want to erase a part of the shape, I just need to remove a certain Points. Moving shape will be just changing the position of the points. That is the plan but I do not know how possible it is.

Can anyone has experience with this type of program give me some advice before I go deeper in coding?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the `repaint();` method, you could set the x and y as integers previously put into an array. Then you change those integers once an anchor for the selection is dragged to fit the x and y for the selection. But then again, you need to know how to drag an object. If you added a mouse listener and sensed if the x and y is in your anchor (you could use inequalities like `(the clicked x) > (anchor X) && (the clicked x < ((anchor X) + anchor width)` and the same for the y. And then when the mouse moves, it moves to the mouse x and mouse y. Then waits until the mouse is done dragging and it moves the image that was selected to the stored mouse x and y. Viola!